# How to set an Image on QLabel from other form in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Before taking up the main subject, please mind that i`m a beginner of Qt.
I made a AddIm.cpp, and I want to set an image on QLabel in MainWindow.

here is my source in AddIm.cpp

```
void AddIm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow mainwindow;
    mainwindow.setImage();
}
```

and here is MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::setImage()
{
    QPixmap pix("./test.jpg");
    ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

and MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
    void setImage();

    ~ some source ~

    private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

it doesn't work at all. so I added a button in MainWindow for testing.
and when it clicked, setImage works. but when I execute setImage in AddIm.
it doesn't work. please let me know why

Comment: I am missing the question. I am missing your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No problem. But posts like that are always in danger to be closed. And even if not, they have a much higher probability to be ignored. So learning how to ask proper questions here is in your own interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with your knowledge with Qt but rather your knowledge of c++.

In `AddIm::on_pushButton_clicked()`, you create a new `MainWindow` object on the stack, create the image, and then exit the function.

When a function exits, all local stack objects are destroyed. This means that your image is indeed being loaded but the window is being destroyed before you get a chance to see it. Even if it survived to live longer than the function allowed, you never show the window so it remains hidden.

UPDATE:

Change `AddIm.cpp` to be the following:

```
void AddIm::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainwindow = new MainWindow;
    mainwindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
    mainwindow->setImage();
    mainwindow->show();
}
```

Comment: That's what i thought, but i don't know how to do. please let me know

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish that but choosing the most appropriate is impossible without knowing what `AddIm` looks like or is supposed to do.

Comment: in AddIm, there is just a button to set an image on Qlabel in MainWindow

Comment: @Daniel, is it so difficult to post the whole code of MainWindow and AddIm? Two classes cannot be that huge. I am sorry to say that, but it appears you knowledge of C++ is so low that we cannot assume anything. We have to see code to pinpoint your mistakes and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not shown the window.

First, you have to create a C++ Class not a single .cpp file. Then add a pointer to the window in your AddIm.h file:

```
private:
MainWindow* mainwindow;
```

Then in your AddIm.cpp file:

```
mainwindow = new MainWindow(this);
mainwindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true); // prevent memory leak when closing window
mainwindow->setImage();
mainwindow->show();
```

And remember to include MainWIndow in AddIm.h

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
```

Comment: it looks like Daniel's a beginner at C++ so you will need to give a more complete example otherwise he's going to either crash his program or get a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you very much, but when i put it as above, it says "MainWindow" does not name a type.  sorry i`m beginner.

Comment: I've put in a line to remove the memory leak.

Comment: Wouldn't it be deleted automaticly with AddIm object ??

Comment: and Daniel. Have you put the #include in your .h file ? Because i don't know where  else could be a problem...

Comment: Only when the `AddIm` object is destroyed, until that time comes, that memory is inaccessible and irrecoverable. If `AddIm` was a window in a monitoring program that stayed open for months without being closed, how many instances of `MainWindow` would persist in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Compare this with with your code to see where you might have gone wrong. I tried as much as possible to code it just like you did. I hardly use the designer, i like to code everything. It works as expected.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setImage();

private:
    QLabel *label;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

void MainWindow::setImage() {
    QPixmap pix(":/test.jpg");

    label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(pix);

    label->show();
}
```

addim.h

```
#ifndef ADDIM_H
#define ADDIM_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

#include "mainwindow.h"

class AddIm : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    AddIm(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AddIm();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    QPushButton *button;
};

#endif // ADDIM_H
```

addim.cpp

```
#include "addim.h"

AddIm::AddIm(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {

    button = new QPushButton("Show Image");

    setCentralWidget(button);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
}

void AddIm::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    MainWindow mainwindow;
    mainwindow.setImage();
}

AddIm::~AddIm() {

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "addim.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    AddIm window;
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what if i want to put the image on Qlabel in mainwindow from addim. i mean addim object is already exist . its made by main.cpp right ? and when i click the button which is in mainwindow, and then in addim, the image show up on Qlabel. thanks.